# Use ActiveAndroid on existing database-content

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, activeandroid

I developed an Android-App where I saved data in a SQLite database using the SQLiteOpenHelper.

I am wondering if I could update my app by using [ActiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/), but in a way that the user data previously stored in the database will be preserved.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no; I haven't been searching for that long, though, so there might still be hope :)

Comment: you can always migrate the content on your old database to a new one that uses ActiveAndroid, after which you can remove the old one.

Comment: I think this problem should have implemented by ActiveAndroid

Comment: Unfortunately ActiveAndroid is no longer being maintained, and I doubt that any future updates will be coming out in the future.

Answer (score 6):

You would have to perform a data migration during runtime after the user upgrades to the newest version of the app. The process could be broken down into the following steps, I have also assigned database version values to each step.

1. The user has all of their data stored in a SQLite database and has not upgraded their app yet. [DB = SQlite v1]
2. On upgrade, when the user is upgrading to the next version of the
   app read all data from the old SQLite database and store it into the
   ActiveAndroid database. [DB = SQLite v1 and ActiveAndroid v1]
3. Once all of the data has been migrated to the new ActiveAndroid database then delete all tables of the SQLite database so that you don't use extra storage space that you do not need. [DB = SQLite v2 and ActiveAndroid v1]
4. In the next release you can then assume that user has had their data fully migrated and at this point it is finally safe to remove all code that was previously referencing the SQLite database. [DB = ActiveAndroid v2]

Comment: For upgrade the database in the next version of app create a Singleton class so that that the copied database will have only one instance. It will update easily.

Comment: D, this makes sense to me... do you think it answers your question?