# ActiveAndroid using exist database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, activeandroid

I am using [ActiveAndroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid) as a third party library in order to working with sqlite database in android, i don't have any problem with creating and using new databases with this library, but i don't know how can i use my own exist database with this library?i want to put my own database into assets folder and load it into [ActiveAndroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid) library.

```
public class Application extends com.activeandroid.app.Application
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        createDatabase();
    }

    private void createDatabase()
    {
        Configuration dbConfiguration = new Configuration.Builder(this).setDatabaseName("dastan.db").create();
        ActiveAndroid.initialize(dbConfiguration);

    }


    @Override
    public void onLowMemory()
    {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        super.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this  [official document](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Pre-populated-databases)

You can use a pre-populated database by following these steps:

Place a copy of the SQLite database file in the assets directory of your application, for example:

```
/myapp/src/main/assets/prepop.db
```

Ensure you set the `AA_DB_NAME` in the manifest file, for example:

```
<meta-data android:name="AA_DB_NAME" android:value="prepop.db" />
```

Now when you deploy your application it will copy the `prepop.db` file from the assets directory to `/data/data/myapp/databases storage.`

Note: This will cause a duplication of the database as it will be both, packaged with the APK and copied to the storage directory.
Ensure the Database Works Properly with ActiveAndroid

To ensure the database works properly with ActiveAndroid take the following steps:

Setup the android_metadata table

```
CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')

INSERT INTO "android_metadata" VALUES ('en_US')
```

If you have not defined the id column name for your models, ensure the primary keys are renamed to the default, Id, instead of _id, which is the standard for Android databases. However, if your data is to be displayed in `ListViews`, for example, it is recommended to define your primary key columns as `_id`. You can do this by simply adding a `id = "_id"` param to the `@Table` annotation on your model, like so:

```
@Table(name = "Items", id = "_id")
public class Item extends Model {
```

Comment: Suppose I do this for app version 2 and app version 1 already have a db file in /data/data/myapp/databases. Will it overwrite the existing db file or ignore the asset file?

Answer (score 1):

"xArthasx" says in [Issue 41](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/41):

> If you have the file (sqlite database) and the tables keep the same structure as the class you made in java, you should be able use the database by coping the file (sqlite database) to the assets directory (project directory) and set the AA_DB_NAME equals to the name of the file.

If the existing database was not created with ActiveAndroid, you probably need to migrate the data; see [Use ActiveAndroid on existing database-content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28569599/11654).

Comment: I have used this solution but it is returning null data, can you please post codes here?